# about gui menu items

Tags: matlab-guide

In my gui, I have created a menu with things like file, view, edit,
compile results, help and etc....using the menu editor in gui layout
editor. I intend to "refresh the gui contents just below the menu"
For eg when a user click view in my gui he would be able to view a
view simulated results page, instead of the "front page" when people
first open my gui.

Can you teach/guide me how to do it? Under the content of menu-view
callback function, I type an openfig('new figure.fig'), so when ppl
press the view menu, it will open up another figure of new contents
and graphics. But It would open another figure, in the end i have two
figures. I like to make the new contents just refreshed below the
menu, and not with a "new page". Is matlab gui able to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can just use one figure, give it a handle name and turn hold on:

```
fig = figure;
hold on;
```

Then have two sets of axes or if you don't need axes, just two graphical objects defined by a matrix, i.e. (axes)

```
screen_1 = axes;
screen_2 = axes;
```

OR (graphical objects)

```
screen_1 = plot(NaN,NaN);
screen_2 = plot(NaN,NaN);
```

then you can change their order in the stack:

```
uistack(screen_1,'bottom');
```

or set them (and any of their children) invisible:

```
set(screen_1,'Visible','off')
```

also, be wary: (From MATLAB)

> Note   In a GUI, axes objects are always at a lower level than uicontrol objects. You cannot stack an axes object on top of a uicontrol object.